# Many new instances of requirejs module

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I am creating a typing game which I have "app.js" as a main and loading "words.js" by requirejs.

I need to use > 2 words but I am still naive with javascript and not sure this is right to do in AMD. Anyone could point me out. I would really appreciate it.

I think it would be like following code but it doesn't work and give me error

"Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function"

[app.js]

```
require(['jquery','app/canvas','app/words'], function($,game_screen,words){
   var words1 = new words();
   var words2 = new words();
   .
   .
});
```

[words.js]

```
define(['app/canvas'],function(canvas){
   var word_list=[{"word1"},{"word2"},...];
   return {
        addWord: function(new_word){
             .
             .
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you're returning an object from your words module: `{ addWord: function() {} ... }`. So in `app.js`, when you set `words` to be equal to the object returned from the words module, you would invoke the functions by doing `words.addWord()`.

If instead you want to use the `new words()` syntax in `app.js`, you would have to change your words module to return a function instead of an object (hence the error):

```
define(['app/canvas'],function(canvas) {
   var word_list=[{"word1"},{"word2"},...]; // not sure how this is used

   function words() {
     // some code
   }

   words.prototype.addWords = function() {
     // some code
   }

   return words;
}
```

Comment: Just to add: the function named *words* is called a "constructor function" since it constructs an object and returns it.